# Polymer property not updating when set from Javascript

Tags: data-binding, polymer-2.x

I have made this simple property (Polymer 2.x):

```
static get properties() {
    return {
        bpm: {
            type: Number,
            value: () => {
                return 0
            },
            observer: "_bpm"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to update it using `this.bpm = 60;` in a function called when clicking a button. If I output the value using `console.log(this.bpm);` it displays the correct value, but my heading `<h2 id="bpm">[[bpm]]</h2>` is not updated and the observer is not called.

When `bpm` is set using something like `<paper-slider value="{{bpm}}"></paper-slider>` it works.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help!

Comment: try to use `this.set('bpm', 60)` instead of `this.bpm =60`. Use the set method to make an observable change.  Your observer seams correct but also you may define like `static get observers() {return  [ '_bpm(bpm)']}`

Comment: this.set is not working: `this.set is not a function`. The observer sadly doesn't work either.

Comment: It's a weird issue I tried to reproduced it but with no success, can you add all of your code ? I created a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/caribouflex/8qj2t1r3/) that may help you (open it on chrome).

Comment: Ok, found the issue: I have set the bpm from `function tap(){ }` outside of the `Polymer.Element{ }` brackets and thought it would work (I'm beginner). Setting a function inside works, thank you very much.

Comment: @p_0g_amm3_ my friend, you can't say `the observer sadly doesn't work either` :)  As I have completed a detailed project with polymer with many observers. I know It should work some how. But I think you could not able to explain your problem as well here. :) Sorry If I am so definite

Comment: Yes, It didn't work because I didn't change the variable correctly. I now used the idea of @Caribouflex and now the observer also gets triggered.

Comment: @p_0g_amm3_ Happy to help. Don't forget to up vote the comment ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be easier for the community to know that this question was answered into the comments of the requests.

**Initial problem** : Binding value not updated because `bpm` property was set from a function outside of the element.

**Correction** : Here a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/caribouflex/8qj2t1r3/1/) (to use in chrome) used to demonstrate how to use the binding.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue due to setting the property from a different function. Putting it here for reference.

#### My code:

```
Polymer({
    is: 'test-test',
    properties: {
        min: {
            type: Number,
            value: -1,
            observer: '_minChangedd'
        }
    },

    _minChangedd: function (val) {
        console.log(val);
    },

    ready: function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            this.min = this.min + 1;
        }, 500);
    },
});
```

#### Problem:

The `setInterval` function had its own `this` and so the expression `this.min` actually refers to `min` of `setInterval`.

Using arrow functions resolved the issue, by replacing the call with `setInterval(() => {...});`